# How to remove double quotes from CSV

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, csv, import, excel

A .csv file I have imported via FTP (too large to manually upload) is wrapping several of the contained columns values in double quotes. When I review the file in Excel the quotes don't exist and the problematic fields are not separated by line breaks or commas.

Is there a query that can be written in Marketing Cloud to strip all values except those between the double quotes? I'm thinking substring may work but the number of characters between the double quotes varies record to record.

Comment: Try enabling the 'Respect double quotes as a text qualifier" inside the import section. Usually double quotes are included in CSV files to make sure that any commas that exist inside of the values do not cause formatting issues with the file.  e.g. `"you, and me", "us"` would only recognize the comma between the 2 quotation marks, while `you, and me, us` would instead display as 3 columns

Comment: Unfortunately enabling this feature resulted in no records importing into the data extension.

Comment: Try doing a 'manual mapping' in a UI import and see if it is registering quotes around your header values in the file as well. This could be the cause of your issue - meaning that it is not mapping any of the columns to your DE

Comment: I tried manual mapping, it had no effect. One thing that did help was to make sure all columns are aligned the same direction. For whatever reason, doing so eliminated the double quotes upon import.